# How to avoid the filtering for some of the object properties in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

**Object is**

```
StudentObj = {name : 'Me', Place : 'Bangalore',uniqueId :'233abc233' }
```

**Html template**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat:'entry in StudentObj |filter:sText' >
         <span>{{entry.name}}</span>
         <span ng-bind='entry.place'></span> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

**And search filter is**

```
<input type='text' ng-model='sText'>
```

**Problem :**

if i search '**233abc233**' in text-filter the row is selecting ,
 But this **should not** selected.

Only on name and place values , the Row should be selected"

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a filter like this to match only two fields:

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in StudentObj | filter:{name: sText, Place: sText}">
```

For more variation of how to use to use filter, please see [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

**Edit:** If you want an `OR` logic (should match if any key is match), you have to roll your own filter, for example,

In controller:

```
$scope.customFilter = function (searchText) {
  function comparator(a, b) {
    return (''+a).toLowerCase().indexOf((''+b).toLowerCase()) > -1;
  }

  var lookInKeys = ['name', 'Place'];

  return function (item) {
    if (!searchText) {
      return true; // no filter
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < lookInKeys.length; i++) {
      var key = lookInKeys[i];
      if (comparator(item[key], searchText)) {
        return true; // if any key is match, return true
      }
    }

    return false; // none of keys are match
  };
};
```

and then use it in `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in StudentObj | filter:customFilter(sText)">
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Mlca2gXvXNVAXEsNbpCI?p=preview

Comment: Issue is still exists as the filter will check for both name and place properties and if either one of the property returns false the logic is failing.

Comment: So, you want an `OR` logic? If either name or Place is match, the row should be shown, right?

Comment: Yes your correct. if i type "Me" it should search either in name or place , if name is returns true then this logic should return true ie row selected else false